# Find matching substring to a regex

Tags: c, regex, substring

Say I got a long string that built up from substrings that all are matching some regex.

For example, I have 2 regexs:

Identifier: `^[a-z]\S`

Operator: `^(:|;|*)`

Given the following string:

```
a12vc+adh*v15
```

And I want to get all the matching items, something like :

```
While(hasNextRegex(str)) {
  printf("%s\n", nextRegex(str));
}
```

Will print :

```
a12vc   (first match) 
+       (second match) 
adh     (third match) 
*       (fourth match) 
v15     (fifth match)
```

I'm using [**slre**](https://github.com/cesanta/slre) library for the regex. C language only.

Do you have any ideas for what I'm asking? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Billi you have 1k rep you could format your question at least :)

Comment: Could you please explain your question better? Neither of the regexes you gave will produce any of the matches you want.

Comment: @Fede when I'm using web I'm doing so. Currently I'm using mobile.

Comment: Since `\S` matches any non-space character, it appears that your identifiers are required to be two characters long and start with a lower-case alphabetic.  So, `aa`, `aZ`, `a+` and `a~` are legal identifiers.  It isn't clear whether `a:` or `a;` or `a*` are supposed to be legal identifiers.  Your explanation of what you expect from your string doesn't match what your regexes want to match.  You need to learn the regex language supported by SLRE, and the API for the library.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I do have some inaccuracies, and that's why I said `for example`. It's not the issue. Assume that I do have a working regexes, the question is how to catch them as substrings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation in `README.md` that is distributed with [SLRE](https://github.com/cesanta/slre) contains an example of iterative search with a single RE.  You need to decide on the RE that you need to use and apply the techniques shown in that example.

Given that the string `a12vc+adh*v15` is to produce the values:

1. `a12vc`
2. `+`
3. `adh`
4. `*`
5. `v15`

You need a regex that will recognize identifiers (initial alphabetic, subsequent alphanumeric) and operators (single punctuation characters).  The SLRE documentation indicates that SLRE does not support `\w`.

Identifiers, therefore, match (if used case-insensitively):

```
[a-z][a-z0-9]*
```

You can add underscore to the pattern if desired/required.

Operators include:

```
[*+-/;:]
```

Hence, a regex that should work is:

```
([a-z][a-z0-9]*|[*+-/;:])
```

Therefore, the code from the example can be adapted to:

```
#include "slre.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    static const char str[] = "a12vc+adh*v15";
    static const char regex[] = "([a-z][a-z0-9]*|[*+-/;:])";
    struct slre_cap caps[1];
    int str_len = sizeof(str) - 1;
    const char *base = str;
    const char *end = str + sizeof(str);

    while (base < end)
    {
        int len = slre_match(regex, base, str_len, caps, 1, SLRE_IGNORE_CASE);
        if (len <= 0)
            break;
        printf("Found token: [%.*s]\n", caps[0].len, caps[0].ptr);
        base += len;
        str_len -= len;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Found token: [a12vc]
Found token: [+]
Found token: [adh]
Found token: [*]
Found token: [v15]
```

This looks like what was requested.